# How to use InputFilter without form class in Zend framework 2

Tags: validation, zend-framework2, zend-inputfilter

My model object implements InputFilterAwareInterface and have getInputFilter() method, that returned Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter instance

I don't  need form in my case, I just need validate elements from array. How I can use Zend\InputFilter\InputFilter for validating data from array without creating form class?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Hope the code is self-explanatory (`setData` to set your array, `setValidationGroup` to check all elements, and `isValid` to get result of validation):

```
use \Zend\InputFilter\InputFilterInterface;

/* ... */

/** @var $data array */

/** @var $filter InputFilterInterface */
$filter = $this->getInputFilter();

$isValid = $filter->setData($data)
                  ->setValidationGroup(InputFilterInterface::VALIDATE_ALL)
                  ->isValid();

if (!$isValid)
{
    $errorMessages = $filter->getMessages();
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Can you suggest an approach to validate only one row from set?

Comment: @yurisnk You can set list of fields to validate in call to `setValidationGroup()`, just use `->setValidationGroup('field_name')` for single field or `->setValidationGroup(array('field_name1', 'field_name2'))` for set of fields in above example.